# Running the rails console command will show the rails default help page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rbenv, rails-console

I have a bit of a weird situation. I'm using rbenv on my production server.
Now I wanted to access the console:

cd $HOME/rails/current
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console

Now Instead of the console opening I'm seeing:

> ```
> Usage:
>
>
> rails new APP_PATH [options]
>
> Options:
>   -r, [--ruby=PATH]
> ...
> ```

Some information:

```
which ruby
/home/myuser/.rbenv/shims/ruby

ruby -v
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [x86_64-linux]

rbenv local
2.6.10

uname -a
Linux myserver 5.15.0-57-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 24 13:43:17 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I also tried:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rbenv exec bundle exec rails c
```

**Debugging**:

```
rails -v
bundle exec rails -v
rbenv exec bundle exec rails -v
# they all yield the following:
Rails 4.2.11.3
```

Comment: Yes. I can run rake routes without problems

Comment: @dbugger: it results in rails 4.2.11.3 (I also updated the question accordingly)

Comment: The only way I can reproduce your error is attempting to run `rails console` in a directory that does not have a rails app installed.